# Surely a foolish error, but I can't see it

Tags: php, html, forms, syntax, jquery-validate

I have a form (greatly simplified):

```
<form action='http://example.com/' method='post' name='event_form'>
  <input type='text' name='foo' value='3'/>
  <input type='submit' name='event_submit' value='Edit'/>
</form>
```

And I have a class "EventForm" to process the form. The main method, process() looks like this:

```
public function process($submitname=false){
    $success=false;
    if ($submitname && isset($_POST[$submitname])){ //PROBLEM:  isset($_POST[$submitname] is always FALSE for some reason
        if($success=$this->ruler->validate()){//check that dependancies are honoured and data types are correct
            if($success=$this->map_fields()){//divide input data into Event, Schedule_Element and Temporal_Expression(s)
                $success=$this->eventholder->save();
            }
        }
    } else {//get the record from the db based on event_id or schedule_element_id
        foreach($this->gets as $var){//list of acceptable $_GET keys
            if(isset($_GET[$var])){
                if($success= $this->__set($var,$_GET[$var])) break;
            }
        }
    }
    $this->action=(empty($this->eventholder->event_id))? ADD : EDIT;
    return $success;
}
```

When the form is submitted, this happens: `$form->process('event_submit');` For some reason though, `isset($_POST['event_submit'])` always evaluates to FALSE.  Can anyone see why?

ETA: after working through the suggestions, it appears that JQuery.validate() is having an unexpected effect on the form submission.  All the fields are submitted except the submit button.  This appears to be the fault of this JQuery:

```
$("form[name='event_form']").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
    }
}};
```

Any thoughts on how to make sure the submit button value gets sent?

Comment: How simplified is this example? If you submit a form using the JavaScript and the `submit()` method, then any submit buttons won't have been activated, so won't be successful controls, so won't show up in form data.

Comment: are you sure $submitname is coming in correctly and corresponds to the name of your submit button?

Comment: are you sure `'event_submit'` gets passed to `$form->process()`?

Comment: @David Dorward: I think this may pointing towards the issue.  I'm using JQuery.validate() on submit.  But I'm not blocking the standard submit action. My understanding was that an onSubmit action did the javascript and then, unless prevented, continued on with the normal form action. No?

Comment: @Ilya Biruykov, @ax: `event_submit` is definitely the name of the button (verified several times because that was my first thought too). Also verified is that the method receives the button name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your JQuery to this:

```
$("form[name='event_form']").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $("form[name='event_form'] input[name='event_submit']").click()
    }
}};
```

Answer (score 2):

do a print_r on the $_POST array and see whats being submitted  - it should output the whole array e.g.

```
 print_r($_POST);
```

Comment: ok, really weird thing happened.  The form is initially validated via JQuery.validate(), then submitted.  When I output $_POST without regard for headers, it turned the JQuery off (expected), and my submit button had a value.  Then when I moved the `print_r($_POST)` somewhere where it doesn't screw up JQuery, the submit button still had a value EVEN THOUGH previously when I did `print_r($_POST)` from that position, I was getting nothing.  Maybe it's some weird combo of JQuery and caching causing the problem?

Comment: @thetaiko: I agree. And I had. But I wasn't getting what I should. Then I moved the `print_r($_POST)` to a different place in the code and got the expected. Then I reverted and still got the expected.

Comment: @dnagirl - check `$_POST` at the very top of your script.  If its there, then something else in your script is changing the value.  If its not, then its a problem with JQuery.

Comment: @thetaiko: verified that JQuery is the culprit. I've added the JQuery problem area to the OP

Answer (score 2):

I broke your code out into a even simpler PHP file:

```
<?php
function process($submitname=false){
echo 'erg<br>';
  $success=false;
  if ($submitname && isset($_POST[$submitname])){ //PROBLEM:  isset($_POST[$submitname] is always FALSE for some reason
    echo 'bwah';
  }
}

process("event_submit");
?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="event_form">
  <input type="text" name="foo"/>
  <input type="submit" name="event_submit" value="Edit"/>
</form>
```

"erg" and "bwah" displayed as expected. Make sure that your class is being instantiated properly, that you're actually passing "event_submit" to it, and that some other piece of code isn't wiping out $_POST before you get a chance to read it.

Comment: @Sam Bisbee: All of those things have verified.  It appears I'm having a conflict with some JQuery validation that happens prior to submit. It doesn't affect any of the other form fields, just the Submit button.

Comment: "and that some other piece of code isn't wiping out $_POST before you get a chance to read it" strikes me as an option, too. Some frameworks (e.g. Zend) blank the superglobals after wrapping them into their own access classes, e.g. if you use Zend's HTTP Request object, you can't check `$_POST`, `$_GET`, et cetera. // Edit: Ninja'ed. Nevermind. :)